# docker exec not working in docker-compose containers

Tags: docker, exec, docker-compose, volumes

I'm executing two docker containers using docker compose.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                   NAMES
eef95ca1b59b        gogent_qaf          "/bin/sh -c ./slave.s"   14 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       4242/tcp, 7000-7005/tcp, 9999/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30022->22/tcp                                                                                coreqafidm_qaf_1
a01373e893eb        gogent_master       "/bin/sh -c ./master."   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       4242/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27000->7000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27001->7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27002->7002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27003->7003/tcp, 0.0.0.0:29999->9999/tcp   coreqafidm_master_1
```

When I try to use:

```
docker exec -it coreqafidm_qaf_1 /bin/bash
```

I get the error:

```
docker exec -it coreqafidm_qaf_1 /bin/bash
no such file or directory
```

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  master:
    image: gogent_master
    volumes:
      - .:/d1/apps/qaf
      - ./../core-idm-gogent/:/d1/apps/gogent
    ports:
      - "27000-27003:7000-7003"
      - "29999:9999"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.master
  qaf:
    image: gogent_qaf
    ports:
      - "30022:22"
    volumes:
      - .:/d1/apps/qaf
      - ./../core-idm-gogent/:/d1/apps/gogent
    depends_on: [master]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.qaf
```

Both Docker files involved have as their last WORKDIR command:

```
WORKDIR /d1/apps/qaf
```

If there is a REAL directory /d1/apps/qaf on the machine's natural file system docker exec works, to some degree. It will open up a shell. However, the mapped in volumes are not available to this shell and the files I see are the ones in the real, natural directory, not what should be the mapped in volume.

```
$ mkdir /d1/apps/qaf
$ docker exec -it coreqafidm_qaf_1 /bin/bash
root@eef95ca1b59b:/d1/apps/qaf#
root@eef95ca1b59b:/d1/apps/qaf# ls /d1/apps/gogent
ls: cannot access /d1/apps/gogent: No such file or directory
```

The volumes work correctly from within the docker-compose context. I have scripts executing in their and they work. It's just docker exec that fails to see the volumes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I installed docker-compose etc. on a different machine and this problem was not there. Go figure. This is just one of those things I don't have time to track down.

Answer (score 1):

The error stems from a the container not finding `/bin/bash`, hence the `no such file or directory` error. The `docker exec` works fine though.

Try with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: /bin/sh also fails. I don't think that's it. If I add /d1/apps/qaf to the host's natural file system, the command works. It finds /bin/bash and/or /bin/sh. It seems like it's got something to do with none of the volumes working for docker exec.

Comment: I got sshd working for now as a workaround but that kinda sucks. I'll have to live with that unless I solve the real problem.

Comment: What does a `docker exec <..> ls` does?